HTML Form not validating inside a dialog box
It is a typical HTML form with textboxes. I am looking for the client side validation you get with forms but it's not happening. I'm sure I did something wrong but I don't know what it is. I am expecting real time validation on my 'required' textbox elements.
Right now I have two buttons, one to open the dialog box and one button to close it.
I'd like to do something with the data being submitted but I need the form validation to happen first so I haven't written out any logic for that yet.
EDIT: I don't know if you always had to do this but I added two CSS properties and it did work so, is this how it always needs to be? This is what I added to my CSS file
input:invalid {
border: 2px solid red;
}

input:valid {
border: 2px solid black;
}



const modal = document.querySelector('.modal');
const openModal = document.querySelector('.open-button');
const closeModal = document.querySelector('.close-button');

openModal.addEventListener('click', () => {
  modal.showModal();
});

closeModal.addEventListener('click', () => {
  modal.close();
})
modal::backdrop {
  background: rgb(0 0 0 / .4);
}

.modal {
  padding: 1em;
  max-width: 50ch;
}

body {
  background-color: rgb(215, 137, 28);
}

dialog label {
  font-size: 18px;
}

dialog h2 {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

dialog text {
  width: 100%;
}

dialog input:nth-of-type(3) {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.close-button {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <h2>An interesting title</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet maiores placeat dolorum corporis nihil sapiente cupiditate animi rem ab tenetur facilis ad hic corrupti eligendi, nulla labore, impedit eveniet repudiandae!</p>

  <button class="button open-button">open modal</button>

  <dialog class="modal" id="modal">
    <h2>An interesting title</h2>
    <form class="form" method="dialog">
      <label>Book Title </label><br><input type="text" required /><br>
      <label>Author </label><br><input id="author" type="text" required /><br>
      <label>Number of pages </label><br><input id="pages" type="text" required /><br>
    </form>
    <button class="button close-button">close modal</button>
  </dialog>
  <script type="module" src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>




Have a look at  reportValidity and  reportValidity

You forgot the submit button.
Look at this post to do it without it.
And the validation occurs when submitting, right now you don't have the validation because it's not submitting.
Submitting a form by pressing enter without a submit button
This works for me.
<input type="submit" hidden />


Use these classes on each input to validate.
classes:
not-null: can not be empty.
ranged: length must be between minlength and maxlength.
num-only: value must be numeric.


const modal = document.querySelector('.modal');
const openModal = document.querySelector('.open-button');
const closeModal = document.querySelector('.close-button');
const notNullInputs = document.querySelectorAll('.not-null');
const numericInputs = document.querySelectorAll('.num-only');
const rangedInputs = document.querySelectorAll('.ranged');


function validate() {
  let err = 0;
  notNullInputs.forEach(function(item) {
    item.style.border = "1px solid black";
    if (item.value.trim() == "") {
      alert(item.name + " can not be null.");
      item.style.border = "1px solid red";
      err = 1;
    }
  })
  if (err) {
    return 0;
  }
  numericInputs.forEach(function(item) {
    item.style.border = "1px solid black";
    if (!Number.isInteger(Number(item.value.trim()))) {
      alert(item.name + " must be numeric.");
      item.style.border = "1px solid red";
      err = 1;
    }
  })
  if (err) {
    return 0;
  }
  rangedInputs.forEach(function(item) {
    item.style.border = "1px solid black";
    if (item.value.length > item.maxLength) {
      alert(item.name + " max length is " + item.maxLength);
      item.style.border = "1px solid red";
      err = 1;
    } else if (item.value.length < item.minLength) {
      alert(item.name + " min length is " + item.minLength);
      item.style.border = "1px solid red";
      err = 1;
    }
  })
  if (err == 0) {
    document.querySelector('#form1').submit();
  }
}


openModal.addEventListener('click', () => {
  modal.showModal();
});

closeModal.addEventListener('click', () => {
  modal.close();
})
modal::backdrop {
  background: rgb(0 0 0 / .4);
}

.modal {
  padding: 1em;
  max-width: 50ch;
}

body {
  background-color: rgb(215, 137, 28);
}

dialog label {
  font-size: 18px;
}

dialog h2 {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

dialog text {
  width: 100%;
}

dialog input:nth-of-type(3) {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.close-button {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <h2>An interesting title</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet maiores placeat dolorum corporis nihil sapiente cupiditate animi rem ab tenetur facilis ad hic corrupti eligendi, nulla labore, impedit eveniet repudiandae!</p>

  <button class="button open-button">open modal</button>

  <dialog class="modal" id="modal">
    <h2>An interesting title</h2>
    <form id="form1" action="page.php" class="form" method="POST">
      <label>Book Title </label><br><input name="Book Title" minlength="2" maxlength="10" class="not-null ranged" type="text"/><br>
      <label>Author </label><br><input name="Author" minlength="4" maxlength="10" class="not-null ranged" id="author" type="text"/><br>
      <label>Number of pages </label><br><input name="Number of pages" minlength="5" maxlength="200" class="not-null ranged num-only" id="pages" type="text"/><br>
    </form>
    <button class="button close-button">close modal</button>
    <button class="button close-button" onclick="validate();">validate and post</button>
  </dialog>
  <script type="module" src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>




You can handle the form as an ordinary form that does a post request (method="post") and then have the cancel button close the dialog. I know that there are more features related to the form in the dialog (method="dialog"), but if you just would like to validate the form and send a post request this is fine.
If instead you would like to let JavaScript handle the form data and maybe do a AJAX request after the dialog closes, the flow will look some that different. Comment if that is the case.


const modal = document.querySelector('#modal');
const openModal = document.querySelector('.open-button');
const form = document.forms.dialogform;

openModal.addEventListener('click', e => {
  modal.showModal();
});

form.cancel.addEventListener('click', e => {
  modal.close();
});

form.addEventListener('invalid', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.target.classList.add('invalid');
}, true);

form.addEventListener('input', e => {
  if (e.target.validity.valid) {
    e.target.classList.remove('invalid');
  }
});
modal::backdrop {
  background: rgb(0 0 0 / .4);
}

.modal {
  padding: 1em;
  max-width: 50ch;
}

body {
  background-color: rgb(215, 137, 28);
}

dialog label {
  font-size: 18px;
}

dialog h2 {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

dialog form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: start;
}

dialog input:nth-of-type(3) {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.close-button {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

input {
  border: 2px solid black;
}

input.invalid {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
<h2>An interesting title</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet maiores placeat dolorum corporis nihil sapiente cupiditate animi rem ab tenetur facilis ad hic corrupti eligendi, nulla labore, impedit eveniet repudiandae!</p>

<button class="button open-button">open modal</button>

<dialog class="modal" id="modal">
  <h2>An interesting title</h2>
  <form name="dialogform" class="form" method="post" action="/post-path">
    <label>Book Title<br><input type="text" name="title" required></label>
    <label>Author<br><input type="text" name="author" required></label>
    <label>Number of pages<br><input type="number" name="pages" required></label>
    <div>
      <button name="cancel" type="button">Cancel</button>
      <button type="submit">Send</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</dialog>



